# How to pass paarmeter from one component and fetch it in another component in the simplest way in ionic-react

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have one component/page with has a ion seacrh bar and passes some id.
This id is then needed in another component/page which is used to call an api.
Im using ionic-react.
Need some simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

visit these two links for better understanding that how to fetch or pass data from one component to another

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/navigation
- https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/example/url-params

This will surely help you